# Any methods to automatically move submodule files when `git stash`?

Tags: git, git-bash

I am reading a programming book with source code while practicing by myself.
So basically I have main project as a host of my own code.
I also `git submodule add https://fakeURL.github.com` to add source code bundled with the book hosted on github in order to consume the source code from my own code from time to time.

After that I found some issues that I had to move the submodule to another directory to resolve them.
So I ran
`git mv path-a path-b`
to adujust the structure of my project.

Everythings going well, sourced code files moved and relavent modifications made in .gitmodules .

But suddenly I remembered that I still have to do some work before the adjustment.

So I tried `git stash` to stash the changes.
The only problem is the moved files not able to be removed and git bash warns that
`warning: unable to rmdir 'path-b': Directory not empty`

The expected behavior would be that `path-b` be removed right after `git stash` automatically.

I also did some research that there is an elegant option `--recurse-submodules` for `git clone`, `git pull`, `git push` and `git checkout`.
What about `git stash`?

Is there any methods would be useful in this situation?

Comment: The short answer is no, there isn't: a submodule is a separate Git repository and it's not really clear how stash should handle that.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I agree with you about that. When I ran `git rm`, git clearly not only moved the folders but also modified .gitmodules file by refer to the new directory as a submodule. On the stash side, git also done the same thing invertly. The only issue is that git knows it had to remove `path-b` and it did, but failed becuase `path-b` is not empty. This situation also happens when you `git checkout` between 2 branches of which one with submodule and one without. The solution is to add `--recurse-submodules` into `git checkout`. No counterpart for `git stash`, right?

Comment: It's true that there is no submodule recursion option to `git stash`. What I mean is: suppose there *were*. Does stashing in the superproject then mean *run `git stash` in the submodule too* ... and if so, *why should it mean that?*

Comment: With `git checkout`, we're doing, well, a *checkout*. We are extracting a whole commit, not making some temporary commits in the repository. This affects only the index and working tree. So recursive checkout means *run checkout in the submodule as well* which again doesn't create any new commits. Perhaps a recursive option to `git stash` would also mean *run checkout in the submodules*, but I don't think it's clear. :-)

Comment: I get your point now. I just think that would be great if most basic git commands could simply work without much work to deal with folders related to submodules. Maybe not a `--recurse-submodules`, maybe a `--force` option to tell git remove the stuff becaming untracked status after `git stash`. Anyway, thanks for the reply.